# WORDPRESS : Custom Field = List?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently on a project that is based on Wordpress. In this project I want a certain type of post, let's say the post-type is "university", to have a certain field to contain a list, or list items. Like : Something 1, Something 2, Something 3, Something 4, etc.

I didn't find anything about that in any plugin or anything. Custom Fields doesn't give me the  option to make list items or a list, only checkboxes or radio buttons.

I want something that could be used in a :

```
<ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
</ul>
```

If there's absolutely no solution then I guess I'll have to code it myself in PHP but if I could skip that part it would be awesome!

Thanks!

Nicolas

Comment: This may belong on webmasters.stackexchange.com, let's see what others think.

Comment: What's wrong with just use a custom field text box? Input comma-separated values, then use PHP to parse them?

Comment: Yeah I'm gonna do that Tom, I just thought this would have been a nice add-on to the Custom Fields plugin haha!

Anyways, thank you! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ACF Plugin www.advancedcustomfields.com

And you add the snap Repeat http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/

Comment: Thank you! I already ruled out my problem with Tom's solution, but this is super appreciated since it is what I was searching for from the beginning! I'll keep that bookmarked. Have a nice day good sir!